# Add text to the end if not already added

Tags: regex, sed, regex-negation

I have the following lines:

```
source = "git::ssh://git@github.abc.com/test//bar"
source = "git::ssh://git@github.abc.com/test//foo?ref=tf12"
resource = "bar"
```

I want to update any lines that contain `source` and `git` words by adding `?ref:tf12` to the end of the line but inside `"`. If the line already contains `?ref=tf12`, it should skip

```
source = "git::ssh://git@github.abc.com/test//bar?ref=tf12"
source = "git::ssh://git@github.abc.com/test//foo?ref=tf12"
resource = "bar"
```

I have the following expression using sed, but it outputs wrongly

```
sed 's#source.*git.*//.*#&?ref=tf12#' file.tf

source = "git::ssh://git@github.abc.com/test//bar"?ref=tf12
source = "git::ssh://git@github.abc.com/test//foo"?ref=tf12?ref=tf12
resource = "bar"
```

Comment: `sed '/?ref=tf12/b; /source.*git/!b; s/"/?ref=tf12"/2' file.tf`

Comment: @DaneSavot Please don't edit tags into the title. We actually prefer the opposite generally.

Answer (score 2):

Using simple regular expressions for this is rather brittle; if at all possible, using a more robust configuration file parser would probably be a better idea.  If that's not possible, you might want to tighten up the regular expressions to make sure you don't modify unrelated lines.  But here is a really simple solution, at least as a starting point.

```sh
sed -e '/^ *source *= *"git/!b' -e '/?ref=tf12" *$/b' -e 's/" *$/?ref=tf12"/' file.tf
```

This consists of three commands.  Remember that `sed` examines one line at a time.

- `/^ * source *= *"git/!b` - if this line does not begin with `source="git` (with optional spaces between the tokens) leave it alone. (`!` means "does not match" and `b` means "branch (to the end of this script)" i.e. skip this line and fetch the next one.)
- `/?ref=tf12" *$/b` similarly says to leave alone lines which match this regex. In other words, if the line ends with `?ref=tf12"` (with optional spaces after) don't modify it.
- `s/"* $/?ref=tf12"/` says to change the last double quote to include `?ref=tf12` before it.  This will only happen on lines which were not skipped by the two previous commands.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed '/?ref=tf12"/!s#\(source.*git.*//.*\)"#\1?ref=tf12"#' file.tf
```

`/?ref=tf12"/!` Only run `s`ubstitude command if this pattern (`?ref=tf12"`) doesn't match
`\(...\)"`, `\1` Instead of appending to the entire line using `&`, only match the line until the last `"`. Use parentheses to match everything before that `"` into a group which I can then refer with `\1` in the replacement. (Where we re-add the `"`, so that it doesn't get lost)